# Kotlin override method for different subclasses without code duplication

Tags: kotlin, minecraft-fabric

I have the following class hierarchy (minecraft modding with fabric):

```
SwordItem, AxeItem extend ToolItem
ModSwordItem extends SwordItem, ModAxeItem extends AxeItem,
```

where ModSwordItem and ModAxeItem are my own classes with some custom logic (SwordItem, AxeItem and ToolItem are existing **classes**. And there also are classes for pickaxe, shovel and hoe).

Now I want to implement some custom logic for my own modded classes (I want to override the inventoryTick method), but I don't want to implement the logic "manually" in both ModSwordItem and ModAxeItem, because of code duplication. I already extracted the logic to an external function, but I still have to manually write the whole override statement and method call to the logic, like this:

```
open class ModSwordItem(...): SwordItem(...) {

    override fun inventoryTick(...): Unit {
        customLogic(...)
        super.inventoryTick(...)
    }
}
```

Of course, that doesn't seem like a lot of code at first glance, but because there are 5 subclasses (sword, axe, pickaxe, hoe and shovel) it really is a lot of unnecessary code duplication. Plus I want to implement different subclasses with different logic. So each time I do that, I have to write the same code 5 times.

My question: Is there any way to tell Kotlin to automatically override the same method for the given 5 subclasses? I already thought about using mixins, but that seems like a weird workaround.

Comment: What's "weird" about mixins? This seems like a great opportunity for that.

Comment: I find it weird to use mixins in this case, because normally when I use mixins, I inject code into existing code I can't directly modify. But I don't have too much experience with mixins, so maybe that's not the main purpose of them.
How would you suggest to approach this problem using mixins then?

Comment: Not an answer to what you’re asking, but I think if you follow the OOP principle of composition over inheritance, you won’t have this issue in the first place.

Comment: @Tenfour04 How exactly would I avoid my issue, when using compositions? I'd still have to define 5 different subclasses that override the inventoryTick method, or am I overseeing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution by composition. It may not fit perfectly with how you're using these classes, but could give you an idea of how you could refactor it.

I have zero experience with Minecraft, so I don't know which classes are yours and which are provided by the framework such that you can't modify them. Assuming ToolItem is a Minecraft abstract class that you can't change, you could define your own intermediate abstract class that uses composition for this behavior like this:

```
fun interface InventoryTickBehavior {
    fun inventoryTick(toolItem: ComposedToolItem, /*...*/)
}

abstract class ComposedToolItem(
    private val inventoryTickBehavior: InventoryTickBehavior = { _, /*...*/ -> }
) {
    override fun inventoryTick(/*...*/): Unit {
        inventoryTickBehavior(this, /*...*/)
    }
}
```

Then you can create a class or singleton `object` that implements the interface and has your common behavior, and use it in multiple subclasses of ComposedToolItem.

Or, if you want, you could create Behavior interfaces for all the different ToolItem functions you might want to override. Then your `ComposedToolItem` class doesn't even need to be abstract. You might not need to subclass it at all, and just build your ToolItems out of instances of ComposedToolItem with various different behaviors attached. However, this depends on how Minecraft uses the class. If generics are involved, it might not be usable in the case.

This could get more complicated if you have behaviors for multiple different things in the class and they need to talk to each other. Game engines that rely heavily on composition (such as Unity) use a design strategy called Entity Control System, where the behaviors can talk to each other by passing String messages up to parent objects, which can then delegate the message back down to children. The attached behaviors just listen for messages they're interested in. But this is likely way too complicated to retrofit into Minecraft just for a mod.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer, this looks like a good idea. But I have some questions/ problems:
1. I eventually want to override more than just the inventoryTick method. To do that, I'd have to define a new interface for each method, right? Then I'd have one "giant" ComposedToolItem class, which overrides a lot of methods. Is there any way to avoid this "problem"?
2. Because SwordItem, PickaxeItem... are classes provided by the framework, I need to subclass those classes and can't direclty subclass ToolItem. Then I'd need 5 different composed subclasses, right?

Comment: My last paragraph answers question 1. Regarding question 2, yes, in this case it’s totally impractical to implement composition. Apparently Minecraft is not designed for it. I’ve read before from Java developers that the source code is kind of appalling—just not very well designed as far as being extensible. Understandable since it was originally written by one person who probably wasn’t thinking of the hundreds of other people who would be modding it later. So in this case, I would create extension functions that have your common code and call them from your various subclass’s functions.

Comment: Yes your right, you already answered question 1, my bad. It's really a shame, that the Minecraft code is so poorly designed. But composition still seems like a valid alternative, so thanks again for the answer!